# How would I set value as zero for this below statement in mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

```
@Html.DropDownList("SID", new SelectList(@ViewBag.SiteTypes, "SID", "SiteName"), "-select SiteName-")
```

Above drop down list is binded from controller.

Comment: Default value to zero or what you meant to say?

Comment: On selecting "select site name" it should pass zero value. @EhsanSajjad

Comment: The 3rd parameter of `DropDownList` is for adding a label option which has a null value. Its designed to work with validation (for instance with a `[Required]` attribute on the property. you clear why you would want to return `0` and lose the benefits of validation but you would need to construct a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` with the first item having `Value = "0"` and `Text = "-select SiteName-"` (and delete the 3rd parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the default option to have a defined value, you need to add it to your options before sending it to the view, something like:

```
List<SelectListItem> yourOptions = db.tbl_Site
    .OrderBy(p => p.SID)
    .Select(p => new SelectListItem 
    {
        Text = p.Text, //whatever field is text
        Value = p.SID.ToString() //whatever field is the value
    })
    .ToList();
var placeHolder = new SelectListItem
{
    Text = "--select Site--",
    Value = "0"
};

yourOptions.Insert(0, placeHolder);
ViewBag.SiteTypes = yourOptions;
```

Then do:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SID", (SelectList)ViewBag.SiteTypes, "SID", "SiteName"))
```

Comment: In My controller:   var SiteTypes = db.tbl_Site.OrderBy(p => p.SID);
                         ViewBag.SiteTypes = SiteTypes; How would I pass default value        @mattytommo

Comment: @MansoorShaik No probs glad I could help